# Laravel: Can't add params to request

Tags: php, laravel, request, parameters

I'm testing my API so I want to create requests, but I can't get the params to work. All I do is to add a param with Hello pointing to World, but Hello returns NULL when I try to get that parameter. What's missing? Here's the code:

```
//This is routes.php:
<?php 
Route::get('/testapi', 'TestController@testapi');
Route::get('/json/locations', 'APILocationController@getForUser');
?>


//This is TestController.php:
<?php

class TestController extends \BaseController {
    public function testapi() {
        echo 'Create the request';
        echo '<br>';
        $request = Request::create('/json/locations', 'GET', array('Hello' => 'World'));
        return Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
    }
}
?>


//This is APILocationController.php:
<?php

class APILocationController extends \BaseController {
    public function getForUser() {
        echo var_dump(Request::get('Hello'));
        echo '<br>';
        return Response::json(array('message' => 'Index all locations based on User'), 200);
    }
}
?>

//This is the output:
Create the request
NULL 
{"message":"Index all locations based on User"}
```

//How is that "NULL"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a "Request::replace($request->input());" solved my problem, I have no idea why:

```
    $request = Request::create('/json/locations', 'GET', array('Hello' => 'World'));
    Request::replace($request->input());
    return Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
```

Anyway, it works now. Forgot to update the question here.

Answer (score -1):

To get GET or POST parameters in Laravel, you should use [Input](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests).

```
<?php

class APILocationController extends \BaseController {
    public function getForUser() {
        echo var_dump(Input::get('Hello'));
        echo '<br>';
        return Response::json(array('message' => 'Index all locations based on User'), 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still returns NULL :/

Comment: How do you test this?

Comment: With the exact same code I just pasted, I just replaced Request::get with Input::get

Comment: No no, what exact url or tool do you use to test the request?

Comment: the /testapi, which we can see since the output first prints "Create the request" which is in the /testapi-function, guaranteeing the creation of the request Request::create('/json/locations', 'GET', array('Hello' => 'World'));

Comment: `Input` is just wrapper for `Request`, this doesn't help OP at all.